# How to add Multiple search field in JQuery liveFilter

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I am outputting info from a database and displaying it in JQuery accordion. Easy, done.

But then I will want to have a lot of this so I wanted to add a search function. Particularly that of [liveFilter](http://anthonybush.com/projects/jquery_fast_live_filter/) as its great.

But I want to be able to search both the title of the code snippet and the content separately. So far I have been able to successfully search everything inside the Div accordion but not individual elements. My attempt so far.

JQuery

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true
    });
  });
  $(function() {
        $('#search_input_1').fastLiveFilter('#code_title');
    });
    $(function() {
        $('#search_input_2').fastLiveFilter('#code_content');
    });
  </script>
```

PHP output

```
<p><div id="accordion"><h3 id="code_title">Printing while loop - PHP</h3>
<div id="code_content"><p>Bla bla bla bla</p></div></div>
```

Html search

```
            <p>Title / Language: <input id="search_input_1" placeholder="Title or Language"> Content / Description: <input id="search_input_2" placeholder="Content or Description">
```

As far as I can see that should work, but its not. Not searching or returning results from either of the **code_title** or **code_content** id'd tags.

I currently having it [running here](http://noopentags.com/code.php) so you can see what I mean, but this is with the first search input searching Div accordion. The second still searches **code_content** so you can see how it doesn't work.

Does anyone know why this wouldn't work?
p.s. there is text in the accordion but is white so blends in.

*also on a side note, if anyone knows how to make them return to collapsed after being searched I would be infinitely grateful to them*